# Duplicate Values in Dictionary with given specific key value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def uniq(x, k):
   for key in x:
       if (x.get(key) == x.get(k)):
           if (x.get(key) == x.get(k)):
              return False
   return True

# Testing
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 4}
k = 'a'
x = uniq(d1, k)
print(x)
```

I am wondering how can I check an if statement twice. I need to figure out at parameter key k if there is a duplicate value in the dictionary. The output of this function should be True at key 'a' and at 'c' it should be False.

Answer (score 1):

to check if you have a duplicate value in your dict you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def uniq(x, k):
    count = Counter(x.values())
    return count[x[k]] == 1

# Testing
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 4}
k = 'a'
x = uniq(d1, k)
print(x)
# True
```

you are counting the number of appearances  of every value and then check if the wanted value appears more than 1 time